# Is there a name for this sort of pattern in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I've thought of this pattern which allows to use base class as a namespace for its derivatives, which may be neat if all your derivatives are known beforehand. One case where this could look nice is when you want to use adjectives for your subclasses. Does this pattern have a name?

```
class Flag
{
public:
  class White;
  class Chequered;
  // ...
};

class Flag::White: public Flag
{
  // ...
};

class Flag::Chequered: public Flag
{
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Worth comparing to the letter-envelope pattern, given the prior knowledge of derivatives. Clearly one could combine the two.

Answer (score 4):

Using a class as a namespace is an anti-pattern. Use `namespace` instead.

Nested classes can't be the subject of a `using` declaration, so without a `typedef` you'll have no choice but to refer to `Flag::Chequered` and not `Chequered` in client code. As you mentioned, all the derivatives must be known beforehand. They can't be forward declared without a definition of `class Flag`. Simply having an enclosing `namespace` has benefits like allowing you to apply operators from `std::relops` to the cluster of classes.

Aesthetics never makes up for language abuse. Here's an alternative:

```
namespace flags {
class Base;
class White;
class Chequered;
}

typedef flags::Base Flag; // independent concept goes into enclosing namespace
```

I don't know of a name for the practice of using adjectives to name classes, but it looks nice. Short names are good, and the `::` operator always helps with that.

Comment: Classes have namespace-like properties, and it may be desirable to utilize those properties from time to time. If you use a namespace `Flag` in this example, you'd have to put the base class in that namespace too, so you would have to have `Flag::Base` instead of just `Flag`.

Answer (score 2):

They're called extremely complicated namespaces without actually using the keyword `namespace`.

The concept itself is called an [Inner class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_class) though, and not uncommon in some languages like Java.

Comment: According to that article, "inner class" refers to the Java construct which is not `static`, and the C++ construct is simply called a nested class, even in Java. "An instance of a normal or top-level class can exist on its own. By contrast, an instance of an inner class cannot be instantiated without being bound to a top-level class."